# How to find out results for not matching particular condition in SQL from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables :

[image]

Person table stores basic person wise details with ID as primary Key
This person can have relationships (father / mother etc), which are saved in Relationship table, however the users for them are created in Person table (e.g. ID = 2,3 in person table), This way we know that 2,3 are related to user 1 (carry).
We also have 3rd table - address, which store user ID wise addresses.(for both a user and his related persons, who are also users)
I want to find out if an address exists for either a user or for his related users in SQL. How to achieve this ?

Comment: which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output is 'Yes' if either the user's or any of his relative's address exists in address table or 'No' otherwise. We mandatorily create this relationship in the Relationship table (e.g. Father, Mother), but not all relationships will have address in the Address Table. (in example above only carry and his mother's address is available).

Comment: Hey @hitesh.gawhade , If my answer is solved your question can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two rules and search on the combined table as below

```
SELECT * FROM
(

SELECT username,id,Address.Address
FROM Person
INNER JOIN Address ON Person.id = Address.Userid

UNION ALL

SELECT username,id,Address.Address
FROM Person
INNER JOIN Relationship ON Relationship.Relatedid = Person.id
INNER JOIN Address ON Relationship.Userid = Address.Userid

) as RES
WHERE Address = 'xyz road'
```

Also you can find [DBFiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9378656e674a0f302f8034fc7b7b0e2a) to workout

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
 select p.id,p.username,(case when a.userid is null then 'No' else 'Yes'end) IsAddressAvailable
 from Person p
 left  join Address a on p.id=a.Userid
```

Output:

| id | username | IsAddressAvailable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Carry | Yes |
| 2 | Carry-Father | No |
| 3 | Carry-Mother | Yes |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e0101d67a1f7c66018dc410a8f8ad97)*